# Confusion in understanding/ following this website for Default Landing page

Tags: liferay-6

I have a confusion in understanding /implementing this page .

Hi , I am trying to follow this website for showing the Default Login page once the user logs in .

Please go through this to understand the question .

http://liferaydemystified.blogspot.in/2011/04/liferay-default-landing-page.html

I have some questions regarding this .

After entering this things inside the portal-ext.properties file

```
login.events.post=com.liferay.portal.events.LoginPostAction,
com..defaultlandingpage.CustomLandingPageAction
auth.forward.by.last.path=true
default.landing.page.path=
```

And i want to use the same CustomLandingPageAction as defined by the author in the web site .

The LoginMVCPortlet is my java file , which will recieve the parameters (Username and Password ) from the UI .

```
public class MyLoginPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

public void checkLogin(ActionRequest actionRequest,
ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
String name = actionRequest.getParameter("name");
String password = actionRequest.getParameter("password");

// Contact the DB for validation .

}
```

**My question is that , how this CustomLandingPageAction and my LoginMVCPortlet class are actually related .**

Is this approach the correct one, or am I missing anything?

How to do this? I am using Liferay 6.1 for development.

Please let me know in case you need any information.

Comment: The example-page is not realy correct. Do you want simple change the landing page after login?

Comment: Thanks Mark , actually what i want is that , on liferay start up i am showing my Custom Screen (Name and Password with submit button ) , once the user clicks on submit button , it will handled by my Custom LoginMVCPortlet class , in taht i am validating the user with MYSQL databse and if he is vallid i want to show him the default Landing page .

Answer (score 0):

put redirection in portlet processAction methode:

```
@Override
public void processAction(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
    //defaultLandingPage = ...
    actionResponse.sendRedirect(defaultLandingPage);
};
```